# Jacoco does not support Cuke4Duke

Tags: jacoco

[Avatar]
2011-12-27 09:59:44 PST
Hi All,

I am trying to use Jacoco for the integration test coverage, and our integration tests are written with Cuke4Duke + JRuby step definitions. When we try to use Jacoco-maven-plugin with the cuke4duke integration tests we dont see any coverage reported from Jacoco.

Do we have any limitations of Jacoco working with Cuke4Duke + JRuby step definitions?

1. There is no coverage reported in Jacoco report.
2. When we run mvn sonar:sonar we get the following warning. 
   [INFO] [22:51:04.237] Sensor JaCoCoItSensor... 
   [INFO] [22:51:04.238] Analysing /home/venki/Projects/charging/trunk/integration-tests/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec 
   [WARN] [22:51:04.240] Coverage information was not collected. Perhaps you forget to include debug information into compiled classes?

Thanks
Venki

Comment: Signature is removed, Please refer the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

Cuke4Duke has been replaced by a jvm implementation of [cucumber](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm).

Answer (score 0):

If you migrate to [cucumber-jvm](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm) you can easily use jacoco to gather your coverage metrics as demonstrated by this [example Maven project](https://bitbucket.org/rlogiacco/atdd).